# Extra y ticks labeling for second y-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How do I use `extra y tick` (or some suitable alternative) to create a second labeled y-axis with the exact same tick mark positioning as the first labeled y-axis, but instead of the numbers `0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1`, use `A, B, C, D, E`?  I have already placed the second y-axis tick mark positions with `ytick pos=both.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ytick pos=both]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use another `axis` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis y line*=left,ymin=-0.1,ymax=1.1]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[hide x axis,axis y line*=right,ymin=-0.1,ymax=1.1,
       ytick=\empty,
       extra y ticks={0,0.2,...,1},
       extra y tick labels={A,B,...,F}
       ]
  \addplot[draw=none] {x};   % dummy plot
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Use same values for `ymin` and `ymax` for both the axis and make use of `extra yticks` and `extra y tick labels` to customise the entries.

Comment: Not really necessary with `extra` for the second axis though, as those are the only ticks that are there, so `ytick={0,0.2,...,1}, yticklabels={A,B,...,F}`. Doesn't really matter much which one is used though, I guess.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are right.

Comment: I know that this is outside the scope of the question, but can you please provide a recommendation for how to do the same thing if instead of `extra yticks={0,0.2,...,1}` I was dealing with `extra yticks={K,L,M,N,O,P}`?  For some reason, I can't get this to work... in other words, my main y-axis is a categorical thing with `yticks`

Comment: @warship Here y values are numbers so you can't use `K,L,...` etc. If you use symbolic coordinates, it is possible. You have to give a solid example though.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis y line*=left,ymin=-0.1,ymax=1.1]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[hide x axis,axis y line*=right,ymin=-0.1,ymax=1.1,
       ytick=\empty,
       extra y ticks={0,0.2,...,1},
       extra y tick labels={A,B,...,F}
       ]
  \addplot[draw=none] {x};   % dummy plot
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```